# Is there any expo professionals that can tell me what I'm doing wrong? (expo)

Tags: expo

I am using a third party react native library:

`https://github.com/terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas`

I am getting errors on a brand new `expo init` just by importing this into `app.js`

Is there any expo professionals that can tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a bare or managed expo app?

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-sketch-canvas` seems to be using a native dependency so you can't use it directly with an expo (Managed workflow) app. To know if a lib is using a native dependency, you can see if it needs a link command during the installation:

```sh
react-native link @terrylinla/react-native-sketch-canvas
```

You will first need to eject your app and you will be able to use that lib.

https://docs.expo.io/workflow/customizing/

Comment: can you help me understand what the rnpm link does?